Invalid argument value. SQLSTATE=HY009 SQLCODE=-99999 with executemany() using Python
I want to insert records in batches in DB using executemany() using python. I have a below code

def find_data(db_string):
    
    json_str = '[\\"{\\"NAME\\":\\"Aman\\",\\"EMAIL\\":\\"aman@gmail.com\\",\\"SALARY\\":785674}\\",\\"{\\"NAME\\":\\"Rahul\\",\\"EMAIL\\":\\"rahul@gmail.com\\",\\"SALARY\\":65489}\\", \\"{\\"NAME\\":\\"Vijay\\",\\"EMAIL\\":\\"vijay@gmail.com\\",\\"SALARY\\":1254798}\\"]'
    
    formatted_json = json_str.replace('\\','').replace('\"{','{').replace('}"','}')
    json_data = json.loads(formatted_json)  
    
    try:
        bulk_operations=[]
        
        with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(new_worker=10) as executor:
            
            futures_task = []
            for json_row in json_data:
                futures_task.append(executor.submit(insert_data,json_row, bulk_operations))

            concurrent.futures.wait(futures_task)
            
            
        if bulk_operations:
            insert_query = "Insert into Employee (name, email, salary, createdTs) values(?,?,?,?)"
            conn = ibm_db_dbi.connect(db_string)
            cur = conn.cursor()
            cur.executemany(insert_query, bulk_operations)
    
    expect Exception as e:
        print("Error")
            
def insert_data(json_row, bulk_operations):
    
    try:
        
        approach #1:
        name = str(json_row["NAME"])
        email = str(json_row["EMAIL"])
        salary = json_row["SALARY"]
        
        current_time = datetime.now()
        
        values = f"('{name}','{email}',{salary},'{current_time}')"
        bulk_operations.append(values)
        
        
        approach #2:
        
        name1 = json_row["NAME"]
        email1 = json_row["EMAIL"]
        salary1 = json_row["SALARY"]
        
        current_time = datetime.now()
        
        record = [(name1,email1,salary1, current_time)]
        bulk_operations.append(record)
        
        
    expect Exception as e:
        print("Error")
    

When running this I am getting below error :
[MainThread] ERROR ibm_db_dbi::DatabaseError: [IBM][CLI Driver] CLI0124E Invalid argument value. SQLSTATE=HY009 SQLCODE=-99999
Can anyone help me on this please?

record = (name1,email1,salary1, current_time). Get rid of the [].

@Barmar, I tried removing square brackets [] and not it is storing in bulk_operations as an individual element and still getting the same error.

@ankit  please edit your question (do not use comments, they are not searchable), and add facts (1) the output of pip show ibm_db and (2) the column-datatypes in Db2 table Employee of the columns.  Your Db2-column datatypes must match the values being supplied in your python code. In particular, when 'createTs' column is TIMESTAMP, then your code must use current_time = datetime.now().isoformat to allow Db2 to interpret the value correctly.
